# Symfony2 cannot load Service

Tags: php, symfony, code-injection

I'm having a problem setting up a service in Symfony. I get the following error when I run the app:

```
The autoloader expected class "HRPortal\SystemBundle\Services\SessionHandler" to be 
defined in file "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/hrportal/src/HRPortal/SystemBundle/Services/SessionHandler.php". 
The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.
```

The class is the following:

```
<?php

namespace HRPortal\SystemBundle\Services\SessionHandler;

class SessionHandler
{

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    public function init($user)
    {
        ...
    }
    ....
}
```

And the declaration of my service is as follow:

```
parameters:
    session_handler.class:    HRPortal\SystemBundle\Services\SessionHandler

services:
    session_handler:
        class:            "%session_handler.class%"
```

I have tried many things that did not work, so I thought I'd ask the community and see what you can come out with.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Namespace should be

```
namespace HRPortal\SystemBundle\Services;
```

That way the fully qualified class name would be `HRPortal\SystemBundle\Services\SessionHandler`

Comment: Awesome, for some reason I tried to do it earlier and it did not worked, but now it is working.